# Amazon SP-API: Access to requested resource is denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-selling-partner-api

I have a problem with the connection SP-API through Postman. I am trying to do this via IAM role (which has an inline policy) and I got LWA + wrote all required data right(client_id, refresh_token, client_secret, access_key)

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
        "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
        "code": "Unauthorized",
        "details": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean for the request:
POST https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token
?
For what request are you trying this ?
Cause if its to get the refresh token,
u gotta:
No params
No auth
No added headers
Yes body

Go to body, select "x-www-form-urlencoded"
at the key & values you write (key :: value)

```
grant_type :: refresh_token
refresh_token :: Atzr|IwE.... (the refresh token u got when u clicked on "Authorize" on your app)
client_id :: amzn1.application-oa2-client.ed752....
client_secret :: a2953b4......
```

As result you should get:

```
{
"access_token": "Atza|IwEBIKJpxfB....",
"refresh_token": "Atzr|IwEBIM9QsQUPTJ....",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 3600
```

}

"access_token" is what you need when you do requests
usually by adding it in the headers as "x-amz-access-token"

Also i'm not sure about this cause i forgot but if you have the IAM Role attached to your app, you have to use STS Credentials
If you have the IAM user attached, you can use LWA

Answer (score 1):

In my case although, I had everything correctly setup I still got same error and it was because **credit card associated was not verified**. You can find it in *Account Info* -> *Payment Information* tab -> *Charge Method*